# Display a list inline

Tags: css

I have a code that I tried to display inline all the contents in a list but the first item is displaying in a line and after that all the other items are displayed in other line. I am confused with the problem. Here is my code,

```
 <ul style="display:inline; list-style-type: none;">

 <li style="background:url("no-color.png") repeat !important; padding:5px; display:inline;"> FEATURED</li>
 <li style="background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 57, 65, 0.9) !important;padding:5px;display:inline;">IPHONE4S </li>
 <li style="background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 103, 57, 0.9) !important;padding:5px;display:inline;">APPLE STOCKS </li> 
 <li style="background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 218, 57, 0.9) !important;padding:5px;display:inline;">IPAD HD </li> 
 <li style="background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(193, 241, 78, 0.9) !important;padding:5px;display:inline;">ITUNES </li> 
 <li style="background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(29, 195, 246, 0.9) !important;padding:5px;display:inline;">STEVE JOBS </li>
 <li style="background:none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(29, 195, 246, 0.9) !important;padding:5px;display:inline;">ICLOUD</li>

</ul>
</p>
```

Also, you can see it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pXh9u/).

Please help me out how can I display all in one line. Thanks

Comment: Don't use inline styling. Use a stylesheet.

Comment: Its actually for a widget that would be inserted separately from other code so I have to do the styling within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tried to use the background `url("")` feature to change the background to an image, but you've forgotten that you are within the `style=` attribute of HTML, so the first `"` closes the style element, without ever reaching to the `display: inline` part.

Changing your quotes to single-quotes `'` helps.

```
<li style="background:url('no-color.png') repeat !important; padding:5px; display:inline;"> FEATURED</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

I looked at your jsfiddle and solved it. change

`<li style="background:url("no-color.png") repeat !important; padding:5px; display:inline;"> FEATURED</li>`

to

```
<li style="background:url('no-color.png') repeat !important; padding:5px; display:inline;"> FEATURED</li>
```

check [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9vxt6/)

Comment: Was it just that small bug? I still don't get it. I would be thankful if you can elaborate it a bit.

Comment: Yep, incorrectly nested quotes. Quotes are optional on the url, so you could also just remove them. In addition, `!important` should never be needed on inline styles.

Comment: Yup, just that small bug, the double quotes around image url closed the double quotes at the start of the style and opened again at the end of the image url. rending it invalid.

Answer (score 1):

It is list item that should be in-lined not the list.

You codes perfects, with a minor update

```
ul li { display: inline; }
```

check a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/pXh9u/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You have a problems with quotes in your first `li`.
And you probably should put the style on another file: http://jsfiddle.net/JJEZS/